# export 'db' (imported as 'db') was not found in '../firebase' (module has no exports)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, json, scss-mixins

I've been trying to run this [React Chat](https://github.com/safak/youtube2022/tree/react-chat) but I'm getting the following error: "export 'db' (imported as 'db') was not found in '../firebase' (module has no exports)". I already setup Firebase and followed the [Tutorial of the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4mjF4sPITE) please let me know how can I fix this, thank you!

Everything I tried is in [This code](https://github.com/safak/youtube2022/tree/react-chat) that you can check out and also try to run it on your local computer if you are interested.

Comment: which of your files throws that error

Comment: All the files from /src/components